# How to disable "Add To Cart" button on select products?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have a Drupal 7 / Ubercart 3 website. How can I disable the "Add to Cart" button on only some products? For instance, if I wanted to list product ABC but did not want to actually sell it online, I'd like for its "add to cart" button to either be hidden or to display a different button that would not be clickable.

The only solution I could find is for D6 (https://drupal.org/project/uc_disable_product).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On What ever products you dont want customers to buy or add to cart, the easiest solution is just hide them using css for that button alone.

```
.parentclass #add-to-cart
{
  display:none;
}
```

Or

you can use [uc_auction module](https://drupal.org/project/uc_auction) and let the products be auctioned for particular period of time.there will be no add to cart button.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do have them hidden via CSS, I was just hoping for more of an admin-input type of solution. I will take a look at uc_auction to see if it will fiy my needs.

Answer (score 1):

edit: new answer/idea

Assign a new toggleable attribute to your products.  Access the product display template (or hook?) and check for that attribute and change/disable/remove the "add to cart" button if it's found.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, but the "Add To Cart" button remains on the page (and is clickable) even when stock is set to $0.

Comment: Sorry, I think I lead you on a wild goose chase there.   I just had a chance to look at an older UC site, the stock controls do NOT work like that. I'm updating my answer for you though, I have another idea.

Comment: That new suggestion is a great idea. I've actually done that before for other fields... I should have thought of that for the add to cart button! I suppose the only issue would be on catalog pages that list a bunch of products, but I could probably just rewrite the "add to cart" button field in the catalog view with the same show/hide that I would use in the product page template, right?